# regular expression: How to match a list of words (allow combination)?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to construct a regular expression to capture units and the corresponding values.

For example,

```
import re 

candis = ['mmol','mm']
test_reg = '|'.join([ut+r"\-?[1-4]?" for ut in candis])
test_reg = r"\b(?:" + test_reg + r")\b"
test_reg = r"\d (?:" + test_reg + r"\s?){1,3}"

test_str = '3 mmol mm'
re.findall(test_reg,test_str)
```

the `test_reg` is constructed to capture the unit `mmol mm` and the corresponding value of 3.

However, as you can readily observe in the example, `test_reg` does not work for a string like `3 mmol2mm` because of the `\b`.

How can I construct a regular expression that can also match `3 mmol2mm` and `3 mmolmm`, which only contains word combinations that are strictly from `candis`? (`3 mmol mmb` won't match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\d+(?=((?:\s*(?:mmol|mm)-?[1-4]?){1,3}))\1\b
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBWOLO/2). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=((?:\s*(?:mmol|mm)-?[1-4]?){1,3}))` - a positive lookahead with a capturing group inside used to imitate an atomic group, that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `(?:\s*(?:mmol|mm)-?[1-4]?){1,3}` - one, two or three occurrences of

    - `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
    - `(?:mmol|mm)`  - a `candis` value
    - `-?` - an optional `-` char
    - `[1-4]?` - an optional digit from `1` to `4`
- `\1` - Group 1 value (backreferences do not allow backtracking)
- `\b` - word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WzIoZC):

```py
import re 

candis = ['mmol','mm']
test_reg = r"\d+(?=((?:\s*(?:{})-?[1-4]?){{1,3}}))\1\b".format('|'.join(candis))
test_str = '3 mmol mm 3 mmol2mm and 3 mmolmm AND NOT 3 mmol mmb'
print( [x.group() for x in re.finditer(test_reg,test_str)] )
```

Output:

```
['3 mmol mm', '3 mmol2mm', '3 mmolmm']
```